# How can fit a keras model with a dataframe of numpy arrays?

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model with self-generated matrices (word vectors).

My data have the following datatypes:

```
print(type(X))
print(type(X[0]))
print(type(X[0][0]))
print(type(X[0][0][0]))
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Then I try to fit my model:

```
model.fit(X.values, y, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=128, validation_split = 0.1)
```

But the following error is thrown:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I tried lots of other formats, but it's even throwing errors for tensorflow tensors (EagerTensor)

What is the problem? Which format is expected?

Comment: It's telling you the issue, and your print statements verify it: `Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray` and your print statement for `X.values` shows `print(type(X[0]))` returns `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Did you mean to pass the values that should be similar to `X[0][0][0]`, which would be `<class 'numpy.float64'>`?

Comment: Check `X.values`.  It would be numpy array, but what `shape` and `dtype`?  `X` is a pandas Series, that apparently contains arrays in each cell.  `values` will then be object dtype.  It may be possible to create a float dtype array with `np.stack(X.values)`.  When TF can't make a tensor from the dataframe or array, the problem is with the input, with the data.  Showing us your model doesn't help!

Answer (score 1):

It's solved using `np.stack(X.values)`